# Conversion of String to type double

Tags: asp.net, string, double, type-conversion, opacity

I am having a simple drop down list as shown below which contains some values:

```
<select id="Opacity">
     <option value="50">50%</option>
     <option value="100">100%</option>
</select>
```

Now I am passing the selected value using ajax call to my webmethod:

```
 $("#btnGetFiles").click(function () {
                ClearImages();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Default.aspx/GetFiles",
                    data: JSON.stringify({imgOpacity: $('#Opacity').val()}),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                    }
                 });
 });
```

Now in my webmethod I'm, getting the value as "50" if I select the drop down value as "50"

Here my problem arises that I have the below code where I need to set that opacity:

```
Dim imageOpacity As Single = 0.0F
imageOpacity = CInt(imgOpacity)
imageOpacity = imgOpacity / 100
imageOpacity = 1 - imgOpacity

Dim colorMatrixElements As Single()() = {New Single() {1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F}, 
New Single() {0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F}, 
New Single() {0.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F}, 
New Single() {0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, imageOpacity , 0.0F}, 
New Single() {0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F}}

Dim wmColorMatrix As New ColorMatrix(colorMatrixElements)
```

Now I need to add **"%"** to the `"imgOpacity"`.If I try to do this way **CInt(imgOpacity + "%")** it throws me an error **stating that string cannot be converted to type "Double"**.

So how do I rectify this?

Comment: Where you need to use that opacity? Depending on that, it may be ok leaving like that, dividing it per 100 (but changing the datatype from Int to Decimal), or making it string so it can contain the % symbol.

Comment: @ivowiblo- need exactly at imageOPacity=CInt(imgOpacity) before that if I modify the single to double it gives me the same error.

Comment: But why do you need to put the % on it? what do you want to do with that variable? calculate something? show it on the page? Save it to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last found the answer.

I have changed my code to this:

```
 imageOpacity = Single.Parse(imgOpacity)
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Why don't you just divide the value by 100? Is it not what percentage is for?</strike>

---

I think this is a case a typo gone un-noticed as your variable names are very similar.

See this snippet

```
Dim imageOpacity As Single = 0.0F
imageOpacity = CInt(imgOpacity)
imageOpacity = imgOpacity / 100
imageOpacity = 1 - imgOpacity
```

Here the R.H.S of the third and fourth statements must take the value from `imageOpacity` and not from <strike>`imgOpacity`</strike>. Change that snippet to this.

```
Dim imageOpacity As Single = 1 - Convert.ToSingle(imgOpacity) / 100
```

And after that please assign `imageOpacity` and not <strike>`imgOpacity`</strike> to the matrix again

Comment: @naveen-First thanks for your reply.But I have done the same thing above.

Comment: @coder: yeah sorry. i still am confused. tell me what value you wanted at the array for imgOpacity if you have selected 50%?

Comment: @naveen-If the user selects "50" I need to pass that value to the webmethod and from there I am trying to set that value "50" to the "imagOpacity".If I leave without adding any "%" to it then it dosen't show me any error and it dosen't add any opacity to the image.But If I do somethng as said above then it throws me an error.